# MySQL workbench Assertion failed Expression:false

Tags: mysql-workbench

After upgrading to the latest version of MySQL Workbench(6.3.9), I receive a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error dialog window displaying the following image:

[Assert dialog window](https://ibb.co/ixqpY5)

This happens about 3-4 times a day. Any known solutions?

Comment: I've never seen this before and your best option is to file a bug report (http://bugs.myslq.com), with more details (e.g. how to reproduce).

Comment: That sounds reasonable but giving more details on how to reproduce isn't going to work because it seems completely random. There is no specific sequence of events that cause this issue to occur.

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me so I investigated and luckily I found a solution that worked for me.

On windows:

Go to `%appdata%\MySQL\Workbench\sql_history`.  There are files in this folder with date in yyyy-mm-dd as the format of the name.

One single file here is very large in relation to the other files, for me its the earliest date.  I deleted this file and have not seen the issue since.  Back it up first if you to keep your history for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After becoming frustrated with having to restart MySQL Workbench over and over during the day, I switched to HeidiSQL,which has turned out to be a light weight alternative that does everything I need. I'm pleased with it so far. If you're interested, you can find more information here: https://www.heidisql.com/